# Double "always": a typo or not?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In [Google style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html) I found the following sentence (emphasis is mine):

> Some projects require that an `if` must **always always** have an accompanying brace.

Is this `always always` a typo, or some kind of amplification?

Comment: The second, "some kind of amplification". Similar effect can be used with **never**. "You must never never eat wild berries."

Comment: @WeatherVane would you like to post this as answer?

Comment: Of course, Google is being playful by imitating spoken rather than written emphasis. Duplication is not common in formal style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **always** twice is not a typo, but is for emphasis, as you suggest.

A similar effect can be used with **never**.

> You must never never eat wild berries.

---

**Edit:**
The term [palilogy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/palilogy) refers to the repetition of a word in a sentence.

Here is a [previous ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119134/what-is-the-term-for-the-double-consecutive-use-of-a-word-with-stress-on-one-of) on the topic. It is similar to this question, but the *first* of the two consecutive words is emphasised.

However *this* question is about the *second* word being emphasised, perhaps with a comma:

> Some projects require that an `if` must always, **always** have an accompanying brace.

Here is [general list](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/Groupings/of%20Repetition.htm) of terms for the repetition of words in a sentence.

Comment: I would use "you must never ever" without comma, or "you must never, never". The first is strong than "never". The second is stronger than "never ever". And then there is "you must never, absolutely never".

Comment: @gnasher729 yes you could use *never ever* but the question was about the repetition. How would your usage translate to the question asked?